# vsftpd problems

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have created a user for vsftpd using 
adduser ftpuser -d /var/www
and then I ftpd in using ftpuser.
issue is that when I try to write to sub directories, it would not allow that
how can I fix tht
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting `write_enable` to yes in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`. Remember to restart `vsftpd` after the change.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that that user needs write access to the directory or file you're trying to write to.